# Fructose vs glucose

Tags: cellular-respiration

I was watching a video on the dangers of fructose and comparing it to alcohol and all of this stemming from the fact that the liver can not break down fructose like it can glucose.  But then I was reading an in depth depiction of glycolysis the first step in glucose catabolism and one of the steps is converting the glucose to a specific kind of fructose so my question is why would our cells convert the glucose to fructose in order to change it to pyruvate if it’s so dangerous?

Comment: Fructose as such is not dangerous, but excessive fructose intake can contribute to the development of fatty liver, for example. There are several articles about fructose on Biology, Medical Sciences and Skeptics SE, so you may want to ckeck those first.

Comment: I don't have much time now, so only as a comment, which I can make to a full answer later on. Without having seen this video, this is with high likelihood sensationalism without much reason. The metabolism of fructose from dietary sources is almost entirely done in the liver, which can lead to fatty liver syndrome if permanently too much fructose is contained in your diet.

Comment: Related: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/82478/detrimental-effects-of-fructose-in-fruit-on-the-liver , https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/34808/is-fructose-the-1-source-of-obesity-in-the-united-states-today , https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/8681/eating-fruit-is-not-so-healthy , https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/19476/is-consuming-fruits-and-veggies-particularly-high-in-fructose-unhealthy

Comment: Fructose will be converted to Fructose 1-Phosphate while glucose will be converted into primarily Fructose 6-Phosphate during metabolism. The position of the phosphate determine the pathway used for metabolism.